# Оптимизация кода в head (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Поставил нужный мне плагин slicknav menu на сайт wordpress. Теперь когда захожу на главную страницу сайта и запускаю консоль браузера, то мне выдаёт в блоке head сайта часть кода из css данного плагина:

```
<style id='slicknavcss-inline-css' type='text/css'>
    .slicknav_menu {
                        display: none;
                    }
                @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                    #responsive-menu {
                      display: none;
                   }
                   .slicknav_menu {
                      display: block;
                      background: #8c8c8c;
                   }
                   .slicknav_btn {
                      background-color:#f7634c;
                      float:right;
                   }
                    ...
```

Хотя у меня в файле header.php нет кода css вообще. Весь код css в отдельном файле .css лежит. Как сделать чтобы в консоле не показывался он?

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы убрать вывод стилей плагина Вам нужно в файле functions.php, который расположен в Вашей теме, вызвать функцию remove_action с соответствующими параметрами
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '#NAMESPACE#\responsive_menucss' );

Comment: я посмотрел в файле плагина самого slicknav-mobile-menu/slicknav-mobile-menu.php есть функция  $ng_slicknav_header = $options['ng_slicknav_header']; если мне её удалить, то не поломается меню? или нужно прописать в файле functions.php фразу remove_action( 'wp_head', '$options['ng_slicknav_header']') как правильно поступить?

Comment: В данном плагине стили регистрируются в действии add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\responsive_menucss' );

В плагине менять ничего нельзя, потом обновитесь все изменения затрутся. Плагин так сделан  что стили у него выводятся непосредственно в теле документа а не отдельным файлом, поэтому скорее всего Ваше меню поплывет, если Вы не подключаете стили иным образом

Comment: а в каком файле тогда правильно что прописать? в файле functions.php фразу remove_action( 'wp_head', '$options['wp_enqueue_scripts', NAMESPACE . '\\responsive_menucss'), да?

Comment: В functions.php

Comment: фразу remove_action( 'wp_head', '$options['wp_enqueue_scripts', NAMESPACE . '\\responsive_menucss')     ?

Comment: remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ .  '\\responsive_menucss');

Comment: вставил эту фразу сайт лёг - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /home/alicoupo/ali-coupons.net/www/wp-content/themes/deals/functions.php on line 26

Comment: что же теперь делать?(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42044/discussion-between-zsiteru-and-sven).